# Fix errors in Tarfix.pl to make a tar file from an android adb backup

Tags: android, perl, character-encoding, adb

I've backed up my android phone using this adb backup command

```
./adb backup -f /mnt/tvshows/android/backup2.img -shared -nosystem
```

I now have a 19GB image, but it won't open with tar. Numerous sites suggest a script called tarfix.pl that can fix the file but when I run it, the output looks like this:

```
[21:40: Downloads$] perl tarfix.pl /mnt/tvshows/android/backup2.img /mnt/tvshows/android/backup.
Wide character in oct at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal binary digit '�������������' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal octal digit '9' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal octal digit '9' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal octal digit '9' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Wide character in oct at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal hexadecimal digit '�������������' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Wide character in oct at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal hexadecimal digit '�������������' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal octal digit '9' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Wide character in oct at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal binary digit '�������������' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal binary digit '\' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal binary digit 'p' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Wide character in oct at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal hexadecimal digit '�������������' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal octal digit '_' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal octal digit '9' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal hexadecimal digit 'Q' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal hexadecimal digit ' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal octal digit '8' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal hexadecimal digit 'v' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Wide character in oct at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal hexadecimal digit '�������������' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal binary digit '' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Wide character in oct at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal hexadecimal digit '�������������' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal octal digit '9' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal octal digit '9' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal octal digit '9' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal octal digit '9' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Wide character in oct at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal binary digit '�������������' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal hexadecimal digit 'Q' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal binary digit 'h' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Wide character in oct at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal hexadecimal digit '�������������' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal hexadecimal digit '&' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Wide character in oct at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal hexadecimal digit '�������������' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal binary digit ' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
Illegal octal digit '9' ignored at tarfix.pl line 107.
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this please? [The script and details behind it is here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1730309) and I've pasted it inline below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#============================================================= -*-perl-*-
#
# tarfix.pl: Fix broken tar files produced by android backup when using
#            -shared flag
#
# USAGE
#   tarfix [<input file>|-] [<output file>|-]
#
# DESCRIPTION
# 
#  'adb backup' is buggy and for some combinations of '-shared' with
#   other options it produces an *uncompressed* (despite the
#   compression line being 1) corrupted tar output. The corruption
#   occurs as follows:
#
#   1. The 512-byte header block for each file is preceded by an extra
#      four bytes "00 00 02 00". Note that the 3rd byte '02' is
#      (trivially) twice the number of blocks taken up by the header
#
#   2. The data is divided into groups of 64 512-byte blocks with the
#      final group being as many blocks as needed to fill out the
#      data.  Before each group, 4 bytes are inserted of form "00 00
#      xy 00" where the hex pair xy is equal to twice the number of
#      512-byte blocks in the group. So, if the group is a full 64
#      blocks, then "00 00 80 00" is inserted. Similarly, if there
#      only Z blocks in the group then 'xy' is equal to 2*z in hex.
#
#   Note: Summing the third bytes of all the skips equals two times
#   the total number of blocks in the tar file (headers + data).
#
#   Note: The file ends with a 17-byte string starting with '78 da'
#   which happens to be the magic number used by 'adb backup' for zlib
#   deflate.  When this 17-byte string is inflated, it yields a
#   1024-byte file filled with nulls (00). This 17-byte string is
#   obviously meaningless and is discarded.
#   
# AUTHOR
#   Jeffrey J. Kosowsky
#
# COPYRIGHT
#   Copyright (C) 2012 Jeffrey J. Kosowsky
#
#   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#   (at your option) any later version.
#
#   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#   GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#   along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#   Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
#
#========================================================================
#
# Version 0.1, released June 2012
#
#========================================================================
# CHANGELOG
#     0.1 (June 2012)  - Initial version
#========================================================================

use strict;
use warnings;
#use Data::Dumper; #Just for debugging...

#========================================================================
### I/O Setup
my ($in, $out);

my $infile = $ARGV[0];
if(! defined($infile) || $infile eq '-') {
    $in = *STDIN;
}else {
    (open($in, "<:raw", $infile) or
     die "Error: Can't open input file: $infile\n");
}

my $outfile = $ARGV[1];
if(! defined($outfile) || $outfile eq '-') {
    $out = *STDOUT;
}else {
    (open($out, ">:raw", $outfile) or 
     die "Error: Can't open output file: $outfile\n");
}

binmode $in;
binmode $out;

#========================================================================
#Skip four bytes "00 00 02 00" before reading each new 512-byte header.
#In a sense, this corresponds to two times the number of header blocks.
while(seek($in, 4, 1) && (my $bytes=read($in, my $header, 512))) {
    if($bytes == 17 && unpack('H4', $header) eq '78da') {
        last; #17-byte (nonsense) trailer at end of backup file
    }elsif($bytes < 512) {
        die "Error: Unknown data at end of tar file...\n";
    }

    #Note: number of data bytes in the file is an 11 digit octal
    #string starting at position 124 in the header. The data is
    #divided into 512-byte blocks.
    my $blocks = int((oct(substr($header, 124, 11)) + 511)/512);

    print $out $header; #Print header

    for(my $i=1; $i <= $blocks; $i++) { #Print data
        seek($in, 4, 1) unless ($i-1)%64; 
        #Skip 4 bytes at the beginning of every group of 64 blocks of
        #data.  Note we are skipping 00 00 xy 00 00 where xy is equal
        #to two times the number of blocks following before either the
        #next group of 64 blocks (i.e. 80 = 128 or 2 times 64 blocks)
        #or the end of the data section. 
        #Hence the sum of all the 3rd bytes for all the skips is equal
        #to twice the total number of blocks.

        read($in, my $data, 512) or
            die "Error: Can't read next block of data...\n";
        print $out $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I had the same problem and figured out how to extract the files, so at least it's a start.

I used HxD, the freeware hex editor, to modify/split the original image file. Based on my understanding of how adb makes the image, it looks like it backs up "shared" last. The bug was that this part wasn't encrypted. So, what you essentially have to do here is to find the point in the original image file in the hex editor where the encrypted portion ends, and the "plain text" unencrypted (shared) portion begins.

To do this, I searched for the first instance of the word "shared". This brought me right to this junction. Just preceding this you should see 00 00 02 00 hex values. You need to split the file selecting just *prior* to this. Selecting directly to the left of 00 00 02 00, Ctrl-Shift-Home to select to the very top of the file, then delete. This will leave you with just the unencrypted part of the file. You save this as a differently named file. Now you can run the tarfix.pl line on this file (no need for the backupdecrypt script), which will extract the shared portion of the image. You'll get an error at the very end, but my experience was that everything there extracted properly.

Next, you have to go in to the original file again and highlight and delete 00 00 02 00 all the way *down* to the end of the file (Ctrl-Shift-End), and save this as a differently named file (leaving you this time with the encrypted part of the image.) On this, you can now run the backupdecrypt script (no need for the tarfix script). This will produce a tar file that you can extract using 7-zip.

FYI, I did get some errors at the end of running the backupdecrypt script, as well as when extracting the tar file with 7-zip, but all the files seemed to extract fine.

The scripts, as well as this explanation that I've just provided, and more details can be found in the scripts' original thread here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1730309

I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do all of this to avoid the errors and such, and even a way to put the image all back together, but I just wanted to go ahead and get the rough method out there so that we can get the ball rolling on a complete solution.